# Is there a way to make function not type-checked in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently implementing a class that is a three-way map, meaning each "index" has three keys and one can retrieve each. The function get is defined as:

```cpp
template<typename returnType, typename getType>
returnType get(getType getVal) {
    if (typeid(returnType) == typeid(getType)) {
        return getVal;
    }
    
    // Here the appropriate value is gotten. Not important for this.
    
    // This is returned just in-case nothing is found.
    return *new returnType;
}
```

This doesn't compile, because getType is not always equal to returnType, which is guaranteed by my check. Is there a way to make this compile, because the getting process is quite expensive. I've tried to just do `return returnType(getVal);`, which only works if `returnType` has a constructor for `getType`.

Solutions I could imagine but didn't manage to pull of:

- template specialization
- disable type-checking (similar to rust's `unsafe`)

P.S: I know this optimisation doesn't make a lot of sense, still would like to know if it's possible to compile.

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<returnType, getType>) {} else {}`. Note that `else` is mandatory, if the else branch doesn't compile when the condition is true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879988/new-vs-new-in-c `*new` is never a good idea

Comment: @Mat It's after throwing an error just so typechecking works.

Comment: You can return an empty value with `return returnType{}`, without a new.

Comment: `return *new returnType;` is a memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeid` is not meant to be used this way at compile-time. If you want to operate on types at compile-time, use the tools from `#include<type_traits>`. `typeid` is meant to be used if you need to operate on types at runtime (e.g. store ids for types in a container or obtain a printable name for a type) or you need to determine the actual type of a polymorphic pointer/lvalue at runtime.

To compare types at compile-time use `std::is_same_v<returnType, getType>`. Since C++17 it is also possible to conditionally compile branches of an `if` in a template, using `if constexpr` instead of `if`:

```
template<typename returnType, typename getType>
returnType get(getType getVal) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<returnType, getType>) {
        return getVal;
    } else {
        // Here the appropriate value is gotten. Not important for this.
    
        // This is returned just in-case nothing is found.
        return /*some returnType*/;
    }
}
```

---

Also note that applying `*` to a `new` expression is practically *always* wrong. You are returning `*new returnType` immediately *by-value*. That is a guaranteed immediate memory leak. `new` returns a pointer to newly allocated memory with a new object of the given type in it. Returning the dereferenced pointer by-value means that this new object is again *copied* into the return value and at the same time the lvalue/pointer to the first newly created object is lost in the copy/move constructor.

To create an object to return directly, do not use `new`. Just return a temporary object using the functional explicit cast notation:

```
return returnType{};
```

or even shorter, since `returnType` is already mentioned in the function return type:

```
return {};
```

`new` is very rarely needed directly in C++. If a variable or a temporary as above also works, then don't use `new`, and if that doesn't work reconsider whether you shouldn't be using `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`/`std::vector`/`std::string`/etc. instead of `new`.